# accessing an object within an array in PHP

Tags: php, salesforce

Below is my following return query from Salesforce. If i try to do `$form_information[0]->Program_Type__c;` I get the following errors:

> Cannot use object of type stdClass as array

Below is my following array which contains an object ?. My question is how can i extract the Program_type__c and Campus_ID__c from my object and save it into variables?

```
print_r($form_information);



Array
    (
        [totalSize] => 1
        [done] => 1
        [records] => Array
            (
                [0] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [attributes] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [type] => Program_Instance__c
                                [url] => /services/data/v22.0/sobjects/Program_Instance__c/a0Ji0000001EUk9EAG
                            )

                        [Program_Type__c] => Field Science
                        [Program_Sub_type__c] => 
                        [Campus_ID__c] => a03i0000002DDBjAAO
                    )

            )

    )
```

### the var_dump

```
array(3) {
  ["totalSize"]=>
  int(1)
  ["done"]=>
  bool(true)
  ["records"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    object(stdClass)#21 (4) {
      ["attributes"]=>
      object(stdClass)#22 (2) {
        ["type"]=>
        string(19) "Program_Instance__c"
        ["url"]=>
        string(68) "/services/data/v22.0/sobjects/Program_Instance__c/a0Ji0000001EUk9EAG"
      }
      ["Program_Type__c"]=>
      string(13) "Field Science"
      ["Program_Sub_type__c"]=>
      NULL
      ["Campus_ID__c"]=>
      string(18) "a03i0000002DDBjAAO"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: can you add a `var_dump($form_information)` to your question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are not traversing the object correctly.

I believe you are after something more like:

```
$form_information['records'][0]->Program_Type__c
```

However, I encourage you to read the introduction about PHP [Arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) and [Object Properties](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php).

Comment: This seems right based on the var_dump, although the error message doesn't seem to match that. Shouldn't it complain about an undefined index, not object being used as an array?

Comment: Agreed about the error. I based my answer on the `print_r()` output. Nonetheless, this matched the var_dump() output as well if this is indeed what the user is intending to access.

Answer (score 2):

Try  $form_information['records'][0]->Program_Type__c;